# Connecting two computers in different networks using socket and Port forwarding

Tags: sockets, networking, port, portforwarding

I have set up a simple client-server communication code and it works well in my computer when my computer itself acts as a server and the client.
Now I am trying to run this same code on two different computers in different networks( different locations) where my computer will act as a server and my friend's computer as a client.

I have done port forwarding in my router as well as in my friend's router for the port which we are trying to communicate. We both have set up a static IP in our internal network behind the router. We both had shutdown the firewall while running the code.

*I am running my code on Jupiter notebook and the same is my friend too.*

**here is my server code:**

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64                                              
PORT = 5064
SERVER  = '0.0.0.0'
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE =  "quit"
Receive_from_client = "get info"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):

    print("\n" + f"[NEW Connection] detected from IP: {addr[0]} & Port:{addr[1]} ")
    conn.send(f"connected to server {ADDR}".encode(FORMAT))
    connected =True

    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)    # decode the msg from byte to utf-8 format

        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)

            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False
                print(f" [Client][{addr}] {msg}")
                print("Your session is disconnected")
                break

            if msg == Receive_from_client:
                print("\n" + f"Send your msg to client with IP: {addr[0]}")
                thread = threading.Thread(target = send2client, args = (conn, addr))
                thread.start()

            print(f" [Client][{addr}] {msg}")
            conn.send(f"Msg received by server with IP:{addr[0]}".encode(FORMAT))

    conn.close()
    server.close()

def start():
    server.listen()
    print("\n"+ f"[LISTENING] Server is listening from IP: {SERVER} ")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target = handle_client, args = (conn, addr))
        thread.start()
```

**Here is the client code**

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64 
PORT = 5064
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE =  "quit"
SERVER = '103.192.207.250'         # SERVERS public IP
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send2server():
    while True:
        msg = input()                        
        message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
        msg_lenght = len(message)
        send_length = str(msg_lenght).encode(FORMAT)
        send_length += b' '*(HEADER - len(send_length))
        client.send(send_length)
        client.send(message)
        print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))

        if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
            print("session closed")
            client.close()


def start():
    print("\n"+ f"[LISTENING] client is listening from IP: {ADDR} ")
    send2server()
```

I have opened the port by going on windows firewall defender and selecting new inbound and outbound rules to open 5064 TCP port.

but still, the code doesn't works..

my server keeps waiting for connection and the client-side after few seconds of running gives this error:

```
TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Even while my server is listening from port 5064 when I scan this port to check if the port is open or not it says closed.

How do I check if the port I have forwarded is for sure open and also how do I get this thing work?

I have tried all of this and if there is any other thing I am missing please tell. I am struggling to get this work for the past 3 days.

Comment: is the server behind  a NAT ?

Comment: Yes, it is. @Vidal